# Complete computer crash for unknown reason

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hardware-failure, crash

I was playing my pc when suddenly my monitor crashed. I got "no signal input" error from my monitor while my keyboard and mouse still had power. I started testing all bunch of stuff (cables, monitors, ram and even cmos battery). Then I removed my gpu from the motherboard and the monitor worked and got back on. Just when I thought I found the culprit for the crash, my bios came up telling me it doesn't recognises my m.2 nvme hard drive which is my only hard drive in it holds the windows 10 os. If it was the only problem I would have thought that something faulty with my hard drive but since I had a problem with my gpu just a second ago I don't think this is it. Someone have any guesses what's going on?

Comment: Are you able to get a BIOS update for your machine?  SSD drives including M.2 are quite common now.

Comment: I can but Im not sure how it would help. I had no problem with the m.2 ssd just a few hours ago. So I doubt that its a bios driver problem.

Comment: Turn on mini dumps and see if you can get a crash dump. Nirsoft Blue Screen view is good to start with.

Comment: Hmm is that a program I need to get into windows to use it? Since the pc don't recognises the nvme with my windows I would need to put another ssd with os. You think I should do that?

Comment: If you cannot (even once or twice) get into Windows, then maybe another SSD is a good idea.

Comment: Yeah it seems like the pc stopped recognizing  my nvme. So in order to get into windows I'll have to put another ssd. Thanks for your help. I really hope nothing is wrong with my gpu, I don't want to try and find a new one right now XD

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looks like a power supply issue. Overload or dying capacitors or something like.

Keyboard and mouse (and the USB ports in general) are usually powered from a separate, much less loaded circuit (+5V standby) that is not controlled from the motherboard and is always on.

It may as well be dying capacitors on the motherboard.

The bad news are that the SSD, the GPU, or both, may be gone for good. But you can still try with another PSU.

Comment: Thanks for the info I will definitly check everything you said, psu, gpu and ssd. But I wanna add that I noted the gpu ventilator is still up and running. I don't know if it tells me anything or if is it good or bad.

Comment: It tells nothing without knowing what this particular PSU does with its fan. The fan may be hardwired to 12V rail, to 5V rail or have its own control circuit.

Comment: Thanks idk why people voted you down for trying to help out. Allready got a new PSU from a friend just to test things. If I could I would have voted you up ;)

Comment: @mashtock now I see that you talk about the gpu fan, not the psu fan. Anyway, the fans are less picky about the power quality and a 12V fan will happily run at some speed at anything between 3V and 20V. P.s. voting is not that much important and you can "accept" even a downvoted answer if it happens to solve your problem.

Comment: Accepted since I have changed my psu and suddenly the gpu is up and running :). The entire computer except from my ssd nvme. Any idea on how to try and fiz it or is it gone for good?

Comment: First, see if it is visible in BIOS or in OS installer - it may have lost data because of on/off cycles, but otherwise good. Second, try it on some known good NVMe capable m.2 port. Third, check if it is still under warranty. If you didn't write some classified informaton on it and there are no physical traces of damage, the seller/manufacturer will probably replace it (or less probably, fix it) under warranty . Failing that, there may be some obscure reset procedure or firmware update tool that may or may not bring it back to life. This may, or may not, lose all your data as well. Good luck.